# memory error of cv::split in KCF tracker

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using KCF tracker which works well for sometime but breaks when I re-create a new project doing something else. For example, I use the tracker to track an object while meantime extract some feature from the object but it really does not affect the whole processing of the tracker, and this error comes as well when the code of feature extraction is commented. The error goes here

```
cv::Mat real(cv::Mat img)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> planes(3);
    //std::cout << img.size() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << img.channels() << std::endl;
    //planes.resize(img.channels()+1);
    cv::split(img, planes);          // memory writing problem? Why?
    return planes[0];
}
```

> KCFD.exe!FFTTools::real(cv::Mat img={...}) Line 135 C++

[image]

BTW, the program is built in debug mode of VS2013. OpenCV is 2.4.13.
I have also modified it to give a 3 or 2-element vector of planes in advance but it does not change.

Comment: Maybe try to use a deep copy to see if the problem persists: `real(myImage.clone());`?

Comment: "is built in debug mode" .. yet I see the call stack mention `opencv_core2413.dll` which is a release mode variant. KABOOM would be the expected result.

Comment: Thank you guys give me good experience. @DanMašek Your eyes are really sharp. I got it.